# ASP.NET MVC 3: Get partial views inside a view folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a FAQ page, which gets the FAQs from partial views located inside a defined view folder. 
Each partial view would contain the question, the answer and some sort order field.

I can't find anything which gives me the complete list of views inside a view folder.

**Update for clarification:**
A FAQ would look something like this:

```
    @model Busker.MVC.Models.FAQ.FAQModel
    @{
        var title = "What is xxxxx?";    
    }
    <p>
      Please register @Html.ActionLink("Register", "register", "Member") here.
    </p>
```

The index page of the FAQ should iterate through all FAQs and first display the questions with and anchored links and then display all titles and questions in blocks.

Another approach I'm looking into, is loading the views in ViewAllFaqsModel. Havent' figured out how to get the partial view into a collection of the model though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of using partial views is wrong. A partial view is created to be reused and not to be a file which actually contains content.

What I would do: Create a file (XML) or database which contains questions, answers and order fields, create a model for it and ouput in on your faq site.

So you could do something like this in your aspx file:

```
<% foreach(FAQEntry faqentry in faqentries)
{ %>
    <h2><%= faqentry.Question %><2/>
    <!-- And so on... -->
<% } %>
```

Comment: I'm with you on most of what you say. The reason why I don't want to use the xml-like approach, is because inside the faqs I still wan't to be able to use the razor features, mainly the @Html helpers.  The current workaround I'm looking at is creating a model which registers all faq-partial-views and then renders them in one go..

Comment: Con can store the FAQ in a xml (in the controller), load it to a model, and still be able to use the html helpers. Te only responsability of your biew should be give form to your data, not to obtain it from the xml. Try to use mvc in the way it was designed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one partial view that you render many times passing each time a ViewModel with the fields that you mentioned.